# Antlr PLSQL grammar not parsing package name correctly?

Tags: parsing, antlr

[Here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/plsql.g4) is the Antlr grammar file for PLSQL.

However, it is not completely correct. For example, I have a package that starts with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME AS
```

The parser generated from the preceding grammar file does not parse `SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME` as the `package_name` (`package_name` is an Antlr parser rule).

To fix this, I have changed this

```
package_name
    : id
    ;
```

To this

```
package_name
    : id ('.' id)?
    ;
```

I have also tried

```
package_name
    : id ('.' id_expression)?
    ;
```

but none of them worked. Antlr still won't include the last `.PACKAGE_NAME` part in the `package name`.

Why is this not working? How can I fix this?

Comment: If the rest of the rules are any indication, you actually want `: id ('.' id_expression)?` (though that shouldn't change what's being recognized in this case).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have tried that too. That didn't work either.

Comment: I would say, it is not working because it is a port of Antlr3 grammar. And it is not finished yet. Another problem with this grammar is, that it is trying to parse PL/SQL, SQL and DDL language at once. But these grammars should use different Lexer beneath.

Answer (score 1):

Such package definition:

```
package_name
    : id ('.' id_expression)?
    ;
```

is working well with the next PL/SQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME AS END;
```

I suppose you forgot `END` and semicolon at the end.

Also, if you find a bug, please add an issue or pull request to an official ANTLR grammars repository, because of this PL/SQL grammar is not completed as it has been already mentioned in comment.